# Azure Active Directory - Is there anyway of creating a custom domain?

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory, auth0

I used to utilize auth0 as my authentication engine but it started to have problems when logging in safari and IE (because it does not accept by default third part cookies). Lately I've been trying to use azure active directory but it has the same problem. Is there any way of creating an authentication service that does not redirect to third part pages.

Note: Auth0 has a custom domain feature but it is only included in paid services.

Comment: See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain.

Comment: "create an authentication service that doesn't redirect to 3rd party" sounds like you want to build your own provider. Have you looked at IdentityServer?